# Unable to POST to concourse REST api

Tags: concourse

I am unable to POST to `https://ci.server.com/api/v1/teams/main/pipelines/test/jobs/hello-world/builds` despite using the Auth bearer token as a header.

There is no issue with GET commands, using POSTMAN to test - is there some other auth required for POST?

Comment: Can you explain how you do "POST" ? Code.. ?

Comment: i'm using POSTMAN with the auth bearer header option - also have tried with GO ```req, err := http.NewRequest("PUT", set, bytes.NewBuffer(yml))
 req.Header.Add("authorization", "Bearer "+basicAuth(client))

 resp, err := client.Do(req)
 if err != nil {
  log.Fatal(err)
 }```